# This code to remove listbox duplicate items gives me an error

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub CHKDUP_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CHKDUP.Click

        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        With GlinkList
            For i = 0 To GlinkList.Items.Count - 1
                For j = GlinkList.Items.Count To (i + 1) Step -1
                    If GlinkList.Items(j) = GlinkList.Items(i) Then
                        GlinkList.Items.Remove(j)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End With

    End Sub
```

When I press the button, it gives me 'Unhandeled exception has occurred in your applcation, InvalidArgument=Value of '975<-Listbox I tems' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would probably be easier to just copy the list first, then put the unique results back:

```
Dim items(GlinkList.Items.Count - 1) As Object
GlinkList.Items.CopyTo(items, 0)
GlinkList.Items.Clear()
GlinkList.Items.AddRange(items.AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not yet test, because I don't have Visual Studio in my computer right now)

```
While i < GlinkList.Items.Count
    j = i + 1
    While j < GlinkList.Items.Count
        If GlinkList.Items(j) = GlinkList.Items(i) Then
            GlinkList.Items.Remove(j)
        Else
            j += 1
        End If
    End While
    i += 1
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think I Got the Answer!

```
If Not listbox1.Items.Contains("sometext") Then
     Me.listbox1.Items.Add("sometext")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim i, j As Long
    For i = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        For j = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 To (i + 1) Step -1
            If ListBox2.Items(i) = ListBox2.Items(j) Then
                ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.Items(j))
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score -1):

I had used distinct method for the following problem but cannot recall how: Create a second listbox2 and make the first hidden then use the following code

```
 Dim i2 As Integer

 For i2 = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
     If Not ListBox2.Items.Contains(ListBox1.Items.Item(i2)) Then
         ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
     End If
 Next
```

Now your second listbox will not have duplicates